# Plotting using xyplot()

Tags: r

I am having trouble understanding the xyplot() function to create plots in R. Below, I have an example of R code that does create a nice plot

```
install.packages("mice")
library("mice")
data <- airquality[, c("Ozone", "Solar.R")]
# Applies regression imputation to Ozone w.r.t Solar.R
imp <- mice(data, method = "norm.predict", seed = 1,
           m = 1, print = FALSE)
xyplot(imp, Ozone ~ Solar.R)
```

The above code creates this image as desired:
[code1 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZSjv.png)

But the code below does not create a nice plot and instead gives me the error message "Error in UseMethod("xyplot") :
no applicable method for 'xyplot' applied to an object of class "data.frame""

```
airquality2 <- tidyr::fill(airquality, Ozone)
xyplot(airquality2, Ozone ~ Day)
```

Why does this occur? I am confused as applying the typeof() function to both "imp" and "airquality2" return "list", so I believe I have the object types correct. Thank you!

Comment: `airquality2` is a dataframe while `xyplot` function from the `mice` package requires a "mids" object : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.14.0/topics/xyplot.mids

Comment: If you want `xyplot(Ozone ~ Day, airquality2)` with just normal lattice, it would work. You are running into an edge case where the generic form of `xyplot` does different things depending on what you pass in as the first parameter. The `mice` version of `xyplot` doesn't follow the same convection is the "default" method which expects the formula first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in R, generic functions call a specific method depending on the "class" attribute of the object passed as the first argument. This is known as *S3 dispatch*. The "class" of an object is not the same thing as its storage mode or internal type, which is what `typeof` returns. The fact that `typeof(imp) == typeof(airquality2)` is therefore irrelevant.

`xyplot` is a generic function, borrowed from the `lattice` package. The `lattice` package itself only defines methods for the classes `formula` and `ts`. It has no method for data frames.

The reason why xyplot works with `imp` passed as the first argument is that `imp` is an object of class "mids", and the method `xyplot.mids` is defined as an (unexported) function in `mice`, so there *is* an available method for it.

The upshot is that, since a method is available for objects of class “formula”, you can easily plot `airquality2` by passing the formula as the first argument:

```r
xyplot(Ozone ~ Day, airquality2)
```

Or explicitly naming the data argument:

```r
xyplot(data = airquality2, Ozone ~ Day)
```

Both of which result in:

[image]